# Iterator not iterating the Class in Java

Tags: java, iterator

```
import java.util.*;

class Person{
    private String name;
    private int age;
    public Person(String name, int age) {
        super();
        this.name = name;
        this.age = age;
    }
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
    public int getAge() {
        return age;
    }
    public void setAge(int age) {
        this.age = age;
    }
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Person [name=" + name + ", age=" + age + "]";
    }
}


public class Iterator {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        Collection<Person> collection = new ArrayList<Person>();
        collection.add(new Person("Komal",45));
        collection.add(new Person("Rahul",34));
        collection.add(new Person("Rakesh",27));
        Iterator iterator = collection.iterator();
        while(iterator.hasNext()) {
            System.out.println(iterator.next());
        }
    }
}
```

OUTPUT:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation
>   problem:      The type Iterator is not generic; it cannot be
>   parameterized with arguments  at
>   java_classes.Iterator.main(Iterator.java:37)

So how will i iter the class person using Iterator as its showing error when i run this code as mentioned above.

Comment: Rename your public class Iterator to something else.

Comment: Thankyou @Uzair Ahmed , Now its working

Answer (score 1):

Your class name is `Iterator`, that shadows `java.util.Iterator`. You could rename your class. Or, you could change `Iterator iterator = collection.iterator();` to

```
java.util.Iterator<Person> iterator = collection.iterator();
```

Your example did not specify the type of `Iterator` it should be (and your own `Iterator` is not *generic*, so if you did `Iterator<Person>` you would have a different error with your posted `Iterator` class).

Answer (score 0):

The issue is with your class name. You have named it 'Iterator' so the compiler thinks that you're referring to this class that you've created instead of the java.util.Iterator class, over here:
    Iterator iterator = collection.iterator();
You can change it to
    java.util.Iterator iterator = collection.iterator();

Or just rename your class that you've created (change the file name too since it's a public class)